# Exchange (2013) Powershell Connection Error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, exchange-2013

I am using Windows 2008 R2 with Exchange 2013

I am trying to connect to my exchange server with the following command but receive an error each time:

`$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://somemachine/Powershell -Authentication Kerberos`

The error I am receiving is:

> New-PSSession : [somemachine.com] Connecting to remote server
>   somemachine failed with the following error message : The WinRM client
>   sent a request to an HTTP server and got a response saying the
>   requested HTTP URL was not available.  This is usually returned by a
>   HTTP server that does not support the WS-Management protocol. For more
>   information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I have tried several things including installing the feature `WINRM IIS Extension` and the advice found here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2027062 with no luck...

Comment: Is the server only running Exchange?

Comment: Yes, the server is only running exchange

Comment: You said you followed the KB article, and you did an IISreset at the end?  Use the EMT tool found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/12/07/3411644.aspx (link and instructions on that page) and see what you can gather from it.

Comment: For future readers: make sure ipv6 is not interfering .. http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2015/10/solved-the-winrm-client-sent-a-request-to-an-http-server-and-got-a-response-saying-the-requested-http-url-was-not-available.html

Comment: @Aravinda IPv6 interferes in numerous ways indeed. Even localhost-access on a system with IPv6 disabled on interfaces: http://serverfault.com/questions/836750